# VB6 >>Get String From Website Table

Tags: string, vb6, html

How can I get string that in a Table of a website   (Not in the Database ! just from the page ! )  in a Specified row and Column for eg. from row 3 and column 1 and my **VB6** Program get that string ! :

Name |  Age | Website | Note         ( raw 1 )
Alex   | 17    |  Stack     |  ------       ( raw 2 )
**Fred** | 24    |  No Site    |  Hello       ( raw 3 )

This table is there on a webpage, I want to get the string that stored in raw 3 and column 1 ( name column ) from this table ( here that string is "**Fred**" ) and save that on a variable.

Please show me the easiest way to do that because I must do it with about 100 tables !

Comment: what is requirement here? Do you want to access record from database or from any webpage? Please provide more explaination

Comment: It would help if you could provide a URL of the page containing the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found exactly what you are looking for here:
http://vbcity.com/forums/t/29011.aspx

There is even an attached example of how to read and iterate through HTML table. All you need to do is modify the code to your needs.

Download example here: [VB6 HTML Example](http://vbcity.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00.00.12.13.88/ReadHTMLTable.zip)

Comment: Thank You a lot ! it's that i need !  <br> **Thanks Again**